# How to convert Map<String, dynamic> to Map<int, String> in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, fluttermap

Here is the expected map

```
{
    1: '1000',
    2: '400',
    3: '800',
    4: '7000',
    5: '5000',
    6: '300',
    7: '2000',
    8: '100',
  };
```

I tried to create it in firestore as seen below
[image]

This is my model *range* carries this particularly map

```
class PackageModel {
  String? id;
  final String? name;
  String? description;
  int? price;
  String? pcolor;
  String? img;
  Map? range;

  PackageModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.description,
    this.price,
    this.img,
    this.pcolor,
    this.range,
  });

  static PackageModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PackageModel(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        description: json['description'],
        price: json['price'],
        img: json['img'],
        pcolor: json['pcolor'],
        range: json['range'],
      );
}
```

Now I want to consume the range here:

updatePackageRange(pack.range as Map<int, String>);

But I ran into this issue

```
Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<int, String>' in type cast)
```

How to I make this **<String, dynamic>** to be **<int, String>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to be more specific with the conversion of the `range` field, and `range` should also have the type `Map<int, String>`.

An updated version of your class might look something like this:

```
class PackageModel {
  String? id;
  final String? name;
  String? description;
  int? price;
  String? pcolor;
  String? img;
  Map<int, String>? range;

  PackageModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.description,
    this.price,
    this.img,
    this.pcolor,
    this.range,
  });

  static PackageModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PackageModel(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        description: json['description'],
        price: json['price'],
        img: json['img'],
        pcolor: json['pcolor'],
        range: json['range'].map<int, String>(
          (key, value) =>
              MapEntry<int, String>(int.parse(key), value.toString()),
        ),
      );
}
```